# Symfony 4 after generating user via make:user schema update crashed

Tags: symfony, mariadb, command-line-interface, generate

I am trying make user via CLI: ([symfony doc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html))

`php bin/console make:user`

This command create User.php entity which implements UserInterface.

But after command:

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

I get errors:

In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 79:

> An exception occurred while executing 'CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL, email VARCHAR(18
>     0) NOT NULL, roles JSON NOT NULL, password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C74 (emai
>     l), PRIMARY KEY(id)) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci ENGINE = InnoDB':
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
>     nual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, pass
>     word VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C7' at line 1

In PDOConnection.php line 90:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
>     nual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, pass
>     word VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C7' at line 1

In PDOConnection.php line 88:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the ma
>     nual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'JSON NOT NULL, pass
>     word VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8D93D649E7927C7' at line 1

**EDIT:**

Info about sql:

Server type: MariaDB

Server version: 10.1.31-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution

Protocol version: 10

Comment: Which version of maria db are you using?

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON Type is an unknown type for your MariaDB database version (cf [type documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/)). Doctrine creates a bad migration script, because it didn't know which version you're using.

Configure `server_version` in `config/packages/doctrine.yml` to:

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    # configure these for your database server
    driver: 'pdo_mysql'
    server_version: 'XXXX'
    ...
```

Replace X by your version, prefixed by `mariadb-` as [mentioned in documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#doctrine-dbal-configuration). So DoctrineBundle will know that JSON is not supported and will replace by another type.

Answer (score 2):

Your MariaDB has to be updated. You have a field with type=JSON (e.g. roles), but that is [only available from 10.2+](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json-data-type/), you have version 10.1.

---

Also, the method you're using (update+ `--force`) isn't very Symfony 4. A better aproach would be:

```
php bin/console make:user 
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

Comment: Thx, but i was accepted another answer because I hate migrations and it work :)

Comment: It takes a little getting used to, but I cant imagine doing without migrations. Much, much more predictable what happens and if something goes wrong, it's easily backtraceable